# if statement never evaluated to true

Tags: java, android, android-intent, if-statement

I have an activity that ask user user to enter his username and password and the system will compare if the user's input are equal to the username and password that i put it.

But the problem is that the system always display a toast that say error in username and password even if the user's input are correct how to fix this problem ?

Can anyone help me ?

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    // for test the username and password

    String username = "georges";
    String pass = "password";
    String username1;
    String pass1;

    Button btn_sign, btn_register;
    RadioGroup rdg;
    RadioButton rd_s, rd_o;
    EditText edit_txt_name, edit_txt_password, edit_txt_o_pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        edit_txt_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxtName);
        username1 = edit_txt_name.getText().toString();
        // Toast.makeText(this, username,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        edit_txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxtPass);
        pass1 = edit_txt_password.getText().toString();

        // Toast.makeText(this, pass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        edit_txt_o_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtOPass);
        btn_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btn_register.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSingIN);
        btn_sign.setOnClickListener(this);

        rdg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdg);
        rdg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (rd_o.isChecked()) {
                    edit_txt_o_pass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });

        rd_s = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdS);
        rd_o = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdO);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * /if the user click button sign in and choose o the system will pop
     * up a edit text that ask the user to enter the key to approve that he is
     * an o and the the system will display the activities and pages that
     * belong to the o, else the user choose so and the the system
     * will display the activities and pages that belong to the so else the
     * user click the register button and the system display the register
     * layoyt.
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSingIN) {

            if (rdg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdS) {

                SignIn(username1, pass1);

                /*
                 * if (username.equals("georges") && pass.equals("password")) {
                 * 
                 * Log.e("username and pasword", username + pass); Intent
                 * i_sign_s = new Intent(this, SignSoldgerActivity.class);
                 * startActivity(i_sign_s);
                 * 
                 * } else { Toast.makeText(this, username + pass,
                 * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

    }

    private void SignIn(String username2, String pass2) { // TODO
        // Auto-generated method stub

        if (username2.equals(username) && pass2.equals(pass)) {

            Toast.makeText(this, username1 + "and" + pass1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // Intent i_sign_soldger = new Intent(this,
            // SignSoldgerActivity.class);
            // startActivity(i_sign_soldger);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error!!!!"  + username1 + pass1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Log.e("username and pasword", username + pass);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is missig a closing comment statement for `SignIn` to be available. As it stands, your code won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you store the text of your `EditText` in the variables `username1` and `pass1` when your activity starts.

Since you didn't have the time to filled both, `getText().toString()` returns `""` probably and hence both are never equals to `"georges"` and `"password"`.

You need to get both text of your inputs in your `onClick` method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSingIN) {

        if (rdg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rdS) {    
           String username1 = edit_txt_name.getText().toString();
           String pass1 = edit_txt_password.getText().toString();
           SignIn(username1, pass1);
        }
```

Comment: thank you sir so it was taken the user's input null because in the oncreate method

Comment: @user3006788 Yes you need to get username and pass when you click on the button. That should work now.